# How can i compare the differences in files from contents in a directory versus a csv using python?

Tags: python, pandas

New to python and this may be a super simple question - I have two dataframes.

Original -

```
dfo

3003490444_3003490433_4581bdb7948c8aa36d27e267.wav
3003497604_3003497592_3557ae5da2aa8a864fc1f94e.wav
3003500674_3003500663_0da8fb89e7d3168d678daddc.wav
3003502980_3003502967_0c4033d9897db71eb3e472cf.wav
3003787361_3003787358_5a57f7bc83908a1736d38bf9.wav
3003220873_3003220851_f199317709b22f5ad8ea5775.wav
3003221139_3003221138_b613b431b493eeaa1df7953c.wav
3003221731_3003221594_ec880e14debb1840fa79ffc5.wav
3003222156_3003222143_e543e6e5d12be4de0b9b490f.wav
3003222366_3003222362_e1b1e2777bde56d40a32920b.wav
```

New -

```
Files

3003490444_3003490433_4581bdb7948c8aa36d27e267.wav
3003497604_3003497592_3557ae5da2aa8a864fc1f94e.wav

3003502980_3003502967_0c4033d9897db71eb3e472cf.wav
3003787361_3003787358_5a57f7bc83908a1736d38bf9.wav
```

As you can see, in the new dataframe called "Files", there are some .wavs missing as opposed to the original. I just want the names of the missing files from the original as compared to new.

I know in powershell this is possible by-

```
$Old = Import-CSV Old.csv
$New = Import-CSV New.csv

$New | ?{$Old -notmatch $_} | Export-CSV Output.csv -notype
```

But I want to do this through python dataframes instead of csv imports through powershell, since i am learning python. Please note that this is just a reprex. The original number of files are 800+, so i would need something to loop through maybe?

For example, the output i would hope for in the above would be

```
Original - New
3003500674_3003500663_0da8fb89e7d3168d678daddc.wav
3003220873_3003220851_f199317709b22f5ad8ea5775.wav
3003221139_3003221138_b613b431b493eeaa1df7953c.wav
3003221731_3003221594_ec880e14debb1840fa79ffc5.wav
3003222156_3003222143_e543e6e5d12be4de0b9b490f.wav
3003222366_3003222362_e1b1e2777bde56d40a32920b.wav
```

Comment: both df's are of same length(including nan's in the new dataframe)?

Comment: no. The original df has 800 wavs and the new one has 300. I just want to know the missing ones

Comment: There are many ways to find series or content differences.  As stated, this appears to be a trivial set difference.  You can easily look up how to read strings from a file, and how to use the difference operators of various collection types (list, set, etc.).  It's not at all clear why you have no code to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you want to do this through python dataframes instead of csv imports through powershell, let's do it as follows:

Make a boolean mask to check for entries in the original file list dataframe `dfo` that is in new file dataframe `Files` by [`pandas.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), then use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter for those entries that are **NOT** in the `Files` dataframe by using negation of the boolean mask, as follows:

Assuming you have the column name called `name` in both dataframes that hold the file names:

```
mask = dfo['name'].isin(Files['name'])
df_new_filtered = dfo.loc[~mask]
```

Output:

```
print(df_new_filtered)

                                                 name
2  3003500674_3003500663_0da8fb89e7d3168d678daddc.wav
5  3003220873_3003220851_f199317709b22f5ad8ea5775.wav
6  3003221139_3003221138_b613b431b493eeaa1df7953c.wav
7  3003221731_3003221594_ec880e14debb1840fa79ffc5.wav
8  3003222156_3003222143_e543e6e5d12be4de0b9b490f.wav
9  3003222366_3003222362_e1b1e2777bde56d40a32920b.wav
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many approaches to do this. Maybe one approach is using the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module.

```
from difflib import Differ
  
with open('CSV Old.csv') as old_csv, open('CSV New.csv') as new_csv:
    differ = Differ()
    diff_file = open("diff-file.txt", "w")
  
    for line in differ.compare(old_csv.readlines(), new_csv.readlines()):
        if line.startswith("+"):
          diff_file.write(line)
    diff_file.close()
```

In the code above, the [Differ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ) class is used. The `Differ` class compares and hows deltas in a human-readable format. Lines that are `extra` are marked with a `+` sign in front and lines that are missing are indicated with a `-` sign. Something like

(If lines are extra)

```
+additional new line
+additiona new line
```

(If the lines are missing)

```
-missing line
-missing line
```

The above sample only shows the `+` forms. You might have to tweak this code to make it work for your needs. There are many ways to do this of course.

(In fact, as you are just learning you could also try to do the same with just the functions "file", "string" modules, flow control statements and arrays alone. (Not elegant but you'll learn the basics)

Comment: Hi vipin, unfortunately, this is not giving me the accurate result. To elaborate, lets say I had a folder and it originally had 800 files yesterday (CSV Old). Today, when I open the same files, i see only 300 of those same files. So my objective is to find the names of the 500 files that are missing in the folder today(CSV New). After running the script you provided, I received an incorrect number of files in diff-file. the number was even higher than the original 800